# How to print an Arrays in JSON Objects?

Tags: json, angular, http

I have this webservice comming from a drupal site.

```
{
    "uid": [
        {
            "value": 8
        }
    ],
    "uuid": [
        {
            "value": "b823efdc-fa44-45ea-a1f4-a804bae4d215"
        }
    ],
    "langcode": [
        {
            "value": "en"
        }
    ],
    "name": [
        {
            "value": "pruthiswebar"
        }
    ],

}
```

This is my class, it doesnt have all the different elements from the webservice, just that one that i need.

```
export class User {
    "uid": [
            {
                "value": number;
            }
     ];
    "uuid": [
        {
            "value": string;
        }
    ];
    "langcode": [
        {
            "value": string;
        }
    ];
    "name": [
        {
            "value": string
        }
    ];
}
```

I want to know how to print it in my component.html

```
<h2>Users </h2>
<ul class="users">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users.name">
        <a routerLink="/user/{{user.id}}">
            <span class="badge">{{user.uid.value}}</span>{{ user.name.value | uppercase }}
        </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My web service comes from Drupal. I am using angular 5. There is a service that consume the json with a simple http get request.

But i got this problem:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: You can use the `json` pipe to display your json into your front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to print the object in your html page (in json format) you can you the anuglar json pipe. (Radonirina already told you in the comments section)

this is how you can use it: `{{user | json}}`

[EDIT]

`{{user.uid.value}}` i think does not work because `user.uid` is an array. So for example `{{user.uid[0].value}}` should work

Comment: thanks, I want to print the name for example, or any other value

Comment: hi @ValRob i edited my post: `{{user.uid[0].value}}` should work in your case

Comment: I got this HomeComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined... I am inside a loop.

Comment: can you add the code from your component.ts file? where you save the data to the users-array? and maybe console.log(users) and post the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate each object from your main object json let say it is myObj.

```
<a ng-repeat=value in myObj.uid>
     <span> {{span}} </span>
</a> 

<a ng-repeat=value in myObj.uuid>
     <span> {{span}} </span>
</a>
```

And so on.